# How to extract the orderconfirmedoid from from the current url using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, string, selenium-webdriver, split, delimiter

I have created an automation script to place an order, My main objective was to get the order id from the URL. I am storing my whole URL in a string this URL has my order id. Now, how I can only get order id from URL. 
This is my URL which I am getting as a string I have also bold out the specific string (order id) which I want:

https://www.fitotouch.com/checkout/orderconfirmedoid=***5e4d212fadda911b34f8862c***&authCode=NWU0ZDIxMmZhZGRhOTExYjM0Zjg4NjJjOjIwMjAtMDItMTlUMTE6NTE6MDkuNDE2WnqeukQEbFNV8aOXKuJtXpOsH_DpTTGB7zCdbXlrhZOR

Below is my code

```
import time
import self as self
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# declare variable to store the URL to be visited
base_url="https://www.fitotouch.com"


driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
#function of our 'driver' object.
driver.implicitly_wait(10) #10 is in seconds
driver.get(base_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys("*****")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('arrow-icon').click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            #FITO NAMES
driver.find_element_by_link_text("FiveSeasons").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/article/section/div[2]/div/section/div/div[1]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/article/section/div[2]/div/section/article/section[1]/section/div/div[4]/div').click()
time.sleep(2.4)

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/a/span/svg').click()
driver.get("https://www.fitotouch.com/cart")
time.sleep(2.4)
#driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(300, 0)")
driver.get("https://www.fitotouch.com/checkout")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input').send_keys("test@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[3]/button').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input').send_keys("test")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input').send_keys("Malik")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input').send_keys("port qasim")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/input').send_keys("5426")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/input').send_keys("karachi")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/input').send_keys("sindh")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/input').send_keys("031545454")
time.sleep(2.4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]').click()
time.sleep(2.4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/div[7]').click()
time.sleep(2.4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[4]').click()
time.sleep(2.4)
url = driver.current_url
print(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
url = url.split('=')[1].split('&')[0]
```

BTW this will work too:

```
url = url.split('&')[0].split('=')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Python* built-in module **`re`** to extract the *orderconfirmedoid* using multiple [delimiters](/questions/tagged/delimiters) as follows:

- Code:

  ```
  #url = driver.current_url
  url = "https://www.fitotouch.com/checkout/orderconfirmedoid=5e4d212fadda911b34f8862c&authCode=NWU0ZDIxMmZhZGRhOTExYjM0Zjg4NjJjOjIwMjAtMDItMTlUMTE6NTE6MDkuNDE2WnqeukQEbFNV8aOXKuJtXpOsH_DpTTGB7zCdbXlrhZOR"
  my_order_id = re.split('=|&', url)[1]
  print(my_order_id)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  5e4d212fadda911b34f8862c
  ```